# Springboot use FileInputStream to read file(chinese name) in linux Failed

Tags: cjk

```
//filePath:/root/pcl/代码安全审计报告.xlsx
File file = new File(filePath);
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
is.close();
```

Charset.defaultCharset().name() is "UTF-8"
System.getProperty("file.encoding") is "UTF-8" too.
exception:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/pcl/���밲ȫ��Ʊ���.xlsx (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)

Comment: 使用控制变量法，发现是supervisor的问题，使用supervisor启动springboot会导致这个问题，supervisor版本4.2.1,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.